Prove that $2 \le (\frac{x}{y-z})^2+(\frac{y}{z-x})^2+(\frac{z}{x-y})^2$
I have the following inequality:
For $x,y,z$ being positive real numbers such that no two are equal show that
$$2 < \left(\frac{x}{y-z} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{z-x} \right)^2 +\left(\frac{z}{x-y} \right)^2 $$
I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz in Engel-Form, but I did not work for me, it appears to be too strong, if applied directly. However, I do not have any other idea, so I would be very thankful for hints.
Thank you very much in advance.
Kind regards
LarryDoc

Without loss of generality, assume $x < y < z$. Set $y = x + a$ and $z = x + b$ where $a,b > 0$. Then,
$$
\frac{x^2}{(y - z)^2} + \frac{y^2}{(z - x)^2} + \frac{z^2}{(x - y)^2} 
= \frac{x^2}{(a - b)^2} + \frac{(x + a)^2}{b^2} + \frac{(x + b)^2}{a^2} 
\geq \frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2} > 2.
$$
